# how to a place a module menu under another module menu in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

i just installed odoo 10 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything is working fine but i want to combine all the HR apps i have installed into a single menu that i will name human resource so when i click on the menu human resource i will see all the hr apps as submenus under it on odoo, i have tried going through the settings menu in developer mode to see if i can do the configuration from there but im not seeing anything that could help me, so please i would be very happy if someone could help me with this in a step by step process thank you.

Comment: Could you edit your question to contain some punctuation? That helps reading it

Comment: LoooL nice one..

Answer (score 1):

You can manage menu items from ***Settings/ technical/ User interface/ Menu Items***.

Here you can create a new menu named Human resources and set this as parent menu for all other menu items you need under HR.

Just remember upgrade any module after that all menu items defined in the upgraded module will be changed to its default.

Comment: thanks so much for the fast response really appreciate i tried what you said but i can see any human resource menu at the top still, this is what i want to do i want to place the timesheet app, employee app, recruitment app, attendance app and leave app under one menu that will just be called Human resources

Comment: @user3013209 the menu will be visible only if you add a submenu(employee) with action for the main menu(Human Resources)

Comment: Thats a nice way